# SQL Server : speed up max() per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm trying to get the `max()` value in a `group by` query on a *large* table using an **index seek**.

I've tried lots of combinations but can't seem to convince SQL Server to NOT do an index scan:

```
create table DataTable
(
    [key] int, --non-unique
    [value] int
)
```

There are approx 100 million rows.  There are only around 20 or so distinct values for `key`.

I have an idea that if I could somehow force the query optimizer to generate a nested loop that does the `max` for each `key` the problem would be solved... but I can't seem to do that.

I've tried all these indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex 
ON DataTable ([key] ASC, [value] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex 
ON DataTable ([key] ASC, [value] DESC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex 
ON DataTable ([key] ASC)
INCLUDE ([value])
```

Select statements tried:

```
select key, max(value)
from DataTable with (index(MyIndex))
group by key

select distinct
    key,
    first_value(value) over (partition by key order by value desc)
from DataTable with (index(MyIndex))

select T.key, (select max(value) from DataTable where key = T.key)
from DataTable T
group by T.key

select distinct T.key, M.Maxvalue
from DataTable T
inner loop join (
    select key, Maxvalue = max(value)
    from DataTable 
    group by key
) M on M.key = T.key 


select *
from (
select 
    key,
    Maxvalue = first_value(value) over (partition by key order by value desc),
    rn  = row_number() over (partition by key order by value desc)
from DataTable with (index(MyIndex))
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: All your indices are nonclustered. Does the table have clustered index / key?

Comment: It's a heap with a unique index (unrelated to this query) but there's no RID lookup happening in the max() query.

Comment: What do you mean by "large", how many rows?  Have you tried it with no indexes?  If you want max(value) for every key (since you don't have a where clause) then a scan will be quickest.

Comment: @CoderBrien can you just try  `select key, max(value) from DataTable WITH(FORCESEEK) group by key`

Comment: @RonBallard approx 100 million rows.  only around 20 or so unique values for `key`.  Certainly there is a way to utilize indexes to avoid reading 100MM rows to compute 20 max values.

Comment: @Veljko89 Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** For the exact query provided - you can't.

The reason for this is that, in order to find largest `value` for a particular `key`, SQL Server has to check all rows with this key. And because your query has no `where` part and looks for all keys, all rows in the table have to be touched. For this, scan is much more efficient than seek.

It's quite easy to compare them: you can use the `FORCESEEK` table hint and compare the resulting execution plans and time / io statistics.

```
select key, max(value)
from DataTable with (index(MyIndex))
group by key;
go
select key, max(value)
from DataTable with (forceseek, index(MyIndex))
group by key;
go
```

If / when your query will actually receive the `where` clause so that only part of the table will have to be searched, query optimiser might decide at some point to favour seek over scan. For filtering by keys, your second index seems to be ideal:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex ON DataTable
(
    [key] ASC,
    [value] DESC
)
```

Keep in mind, however, that the threshold at which it might happen depends very much on your data cardinality, index fragmentation, statistics being up-to-date, database engine version / edition, trace flags and some other stuff too esoteric and arcane to mention it here. I mean, do not expect it to be some sort of a constant.

Comment: Hi Roger, thanks for the reply.  You are losing me on the logic though.  The table has 100MM rows so an index scan is an i/o killer (not to mention on my actual table each row is much bigger than the example).  If I chose to write a loop over the 20 or so keys inserting key/max(value) into a temp table that would be *much* more performant since each iteration is an index seek.  I just have to think there is a way to do it with a single query though.

Comment: @CoderBrien If your cardinalities are that much skewed, I would recommend to store these aggregates in a separate table. The best way to keep it in sync depends on how your data is changed: might be a trigger, or a side branch in the SSIS data flow, or whatever else that you have.

Comment: yeah, i know i can do that.  so then i just run a really slow query less often or add a shitload of complexity.  not really the solution i'm looking for.  there has to be a way.

Comment: Yes, there is a way, and it's called "stored preaggregates". How the data is changed in your big table? Inserts, updates, bulk load?

Comment: bulk load.  ya, but "stored preaggregates" is just a name for "track and update derivative state by yourself and don't make any mistakes doing it", right?  not a built in feature?

Comment: You write it, you test it, and you don't have to touch it any more. No different from any other kind of code, really. Maximum values, in particular, can be easily obtained during SSIS load. Sure, it will probably require some package-level scripting, but in my 15 years in the trade I have never seen any silver bullet of this kind.

Comment: whoa nelly... not using ssis and i'm aware that i can add a ton of complexity to track delta(state).  not interested in pursuing this line of action.  sometimes it's best to say "i don't know" when you can't answer a question as posed.

Comment: Good luck finding the answer you want, then.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to @Roger Wolf and his explanation.

Your question is good from learning point of view.

I tried to create sample data and get `Index Seek`

```
create table DataTable
(
    [key] int, --non-unique
    [value] int
)

insert into DataTable WITH (TABLOCK)
([key],value )
select rn/500000 ,rn/100
from
(
select top (10000000) ROW_NUMBER()over(order by a.number)rn 
from 
master..spt_values a
,master..spt_values b
,master..spt_values c
)t4
```

Here there is 22 distinct key with around 5000 value each key

If my sample data logic is wrong then you can correct and tell me.i try that in my machine.

I ma using this index

```
CREATE nonCLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex
ON DataTable ([key] ASC)
INCLUDE ([value])
```

Now i use old query,

```
select a.[key], max(a.value) value
from DataTable a
group by [key]
```

It take less than 1 second ,but it has `Index Scan`.
Why ? Explanation is same as @Roger.Query plan is simple.

now like you said if you loop throw those 22 rows then you do get index seek.
I am using Recursive method here

```
;with RecursiveCTE as
(
select [key],cast(0 as bigint)rn,max(value)value
from DataTable
where [key]=0  
group by [key]

union ALL

select [key],rn,t4.value FROM
(
select c.[key]+1 [key],max(a.value)over(order by a.[key]) value
,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(order by a.[key]) rn

from DataTable a
inner join RecursiveCTE c
on a.[key]=c.[key]
)t4 where rn=1
)

select [key],value FROM
RecursiveCTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Here I it `27 second` to return `22 rows`.I do get `Index Seek` in both part of recursive.Query plan is complex.I don't know how to attach it.

Now decide? I haven't tried with loop,you can compare and update us.